# How to encode URLs for Laravel 4 on shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel-4, urlencode, url-encoding, laravel-routing

My project works properly with WAMP on a local host.

On the other hand, on a shared production hosting, I have some troubles with one of my routes:
`Route::get('sth/{encodedURI}',array('uses'=>'MyController@sth'))->where('encodedURI','.*');`

The URL looks like this:
`http://mywebsite.com/sth/http%3A%2F%2Fany-url.com`

The route does not work, as I get a 404 error, as soon as there are some encoded characters in the url..

I guess the trick is not so complicated... but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I imagined a quite dirty workaround. But it's working.

Before sending the URL, I replace the problematic `%` by `@@@`which is supposed to be quite rare.

Then, on the targeted page, I retranslate the `@@@`into `%` before decoding properly the URI component.